# Saving cropped image into SQLite database

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I understand this question has been asked before and I have researched possible solutions with no luck so here it goes. I am trying to save an cropped image into a sqlite database. I am using the [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) cropper library as follows in my onActivityResult() method:

Everything works except the part where I am trying to save the image as a bitmap. I keep getting null. I can however populate my ImageView with the line

ivTroopPhoto.setImageURI(result.getUri());

If anyone has used this API an can help me out with this issue.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == PIC_FROM_CAMERA) || (requestCode == PIC_FROM_GALLERY)) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri picUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(picUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setFixAspectRatio(true)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ibCameraIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ivTroopPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivTroopPhoto.setImageURI(result.getUri());
            tvTroopPhoto.setText(R.string.change_photo);

            Log.d("dozer74", "==============================> Image Uri: " + result.getUri().getPath());

            //Uri imageUir = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), result.getUri());
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Log.d("dozer74", "==========> Encoded Base64 Image: " + encoded);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, String.format("Cropping failed: %s", result.getError()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I keep getting null`. What becomes null?

Comment: `result.getUri().getPath()`. What is the value? And that of the `.toString()` member?

Comment: There are many image resource manager in Android. Don't do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work it out. I used the api's imageview and was able to get the image as a bitmap.